# Array/tabela Lua para JavaScript

Tags: javascript, lua

Tenho um *array* na linguagem Lua, e queria passar os seus elementos para uma *array* JavaScript. Exemplo do *array* Lua:

```
tabela_y = {0, 1, 2}
```

Em PHP existe o implode, não sei se é possível em Lua.

Comment: Você quer transformar o *array* em *string* separada por vírgulas, é isto?

Comment: Sim, para depois voltar a por essa string para um array.

Comment: Ao invés de fazer isso na mão, uma alternativa que vc podia dar uma olhada é usar uma bibliotecas de serialização JSON existente. Assim vc se protege contra ataques de injeção de javascript (XSS) caso a sua tabela contenha strings provenientes do usuário (ao invés de somente números)

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Você pode aceitá-la?

Answer (score 4):

Existe a função `concat()` que faz isto:

```
tabela_y = {0, 1, 2}
print(table.concat(tabela_y, ","))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yETe7y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ivenuttn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/ConcatTable.lua).

Comment: Queria passar esses valores da tabela para um array em javascript.

Comment: Já estava em uma*array*. Se precisa mais que isto depende do que você está fazendo. Você já deve saber que não se passa coisas de Lua para JS, você deve montar uma página colocando o que você quer.